# Azure Table Storage: a script to populate new column for existing tables

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-table-storage

I have some tables in my Azure Table Storage and need to deploy a script to populate a new column with empty data for all of them.

I know that some management could be done via PowerShell, but I was unable to find any relevant example or documentation on how to perform this task.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the data type of this column you're trying to create?

Comment: Could be String or int, it will be numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the PowerShell script, please refer to the following code:

```
Install-Module -Name AzTable

$groupName=""
$StorageAccountName = ""
$StorageAccountKey = ""
$vaule=" "
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$tables = Get-AzStorageTable -Context $context
Foreach($table in $tables){
    $table = Get-AzTableTable -storageAccountName $StorageAccountName -resourceGroup $groupName="" -TableName
    $entities=Get-AzTableRow -Table $table
    ForEach($e in $entities){
        $entity = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity($e.PartitionKey,$e.RowKey)
        $entity.Properties.Add("Name", $vaue)
        $table.Execute([Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrMerge($entity))
        Get-AzTableRow -Table $table -PartitionKey $e.PartitionKey -RowKey $e.RowKey
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I also do it for multiple tables with one script? For example if table name has "azup" in it?

Comment: Would this line help me with the list of tables? $tables = GetAzureStorageTable -Name azup*

Comment: @Jdreamer. Thanks for your response. I have updated my script. Please check it.

Comment: I am getting an error during the import of AzTable module at script execution that AzureRm.Profile is already loaded

Comment: Well, I've managed to fix the Rm issue, but now the exception is now this line: `$table.Execute([Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrMerge($entity))`

Comment: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable] does
not contain a method named 'Execute'.

Comment: Seems to be a little bug in the script, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> I have some tables in my Azure Table Storage and need to deploy a
>   script to populate a new column with empty data for all of them.

Basically Azure Table is a key/value pair store so it can't really have columns (key) with no data (value) in it. This is applicable to all supported data types with an exception of `String` data type where you can store an empty string (it's still not null) as value for a key.

As to how you go about doing it, here're the steps you can follow:

1. Fetch the entities for which you wish to add a key. To reduce the response payload, you can simply fetch the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` attributes.
2. For each entity you receive, simply add a new attribute. Please ensure that the attribute's data type is `String` and set the value of that attribute to empty string (`""`).
3. Last you would want to call [`Merge Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/merge-entity) operation on those entities. This will ensure that only the new attribute will get added. All other existing attributes in that entity will remain unchanged.

Unfortunately I am not too familiar with PowerShell to provide exact syntax. But this should give you enough idea to get going.