# Cannot find an overload for "ExecuteQuery" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-table-storage

**strong text**Cannot find an overload for "ExecuteQuery" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRmStorageTable\1.0.0.23\AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1:369 char:2
+     $result = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($tableQuery)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Cannot find an overload for "Execute" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRmStorageTable\1.0.0.23\AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1:191 char:11
+ ...      return ($table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Cannot find an overload for "Execute" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:1
+ [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity,Microsoft.Wi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

THIS IS WHAT THE AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper LOOKS LIKE 
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1 - PowerShell Module that contains all functions related to manipulating Azure Storage Table rows/entities.
.DESCRIPTION
    AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1 - PowerShell Module that contains all functions related to manipulating Azure Storage Table rows/entities.
.NOTES
    Make sure the latest Azure PowerShell module is installed since we have a dependency on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll and 
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.dll.

```
If running this module from Azure Automation, please make sure you check out this blog post for more information:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulomarques/2017/01/17/working-with-azure-storage-tables-from-powershell/
```

## >

## Requires -Modules Azure.Storage, AzureRm.Profile, AzureRm.Storage, AzureRM.Resources

## Module Functions

function GetLatestFullAssemblyName
{
    param
    (
        [string]$dllName
    )

```
# getting list of all assemblies
$assemblies = [appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | Where-Object {$_.location -like "*$dllName"} 
if ($assemblies -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not identify any assembly related to DLL named $dllName"
}

$sanitazedAssemblyList = @()
foreach ($assembly in $assemblies)
{
    [version]$version = $assembly.fullname.split(",")[1].split("=")[1]
    $sanitazedAssemblyList += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{"version"=$version;"fullName"=$assembly.fullname}
}

return ($sanitazedAssemblyList | Sort-Object version -Descending)[0]
```

}

## Getting latest Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll full Assembly name

$assemblySN = (GetLatestFullAssemblyName -dllName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll").fullname

function Test-AzureStorageTableEmptyKeys
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [string]$partitionKey,
        [String]$rowKey
    )

```
$cosmosDBEmptyKeysErrorMessage = "Cosmos DB table API does not accept empty partition or row keys when using CloudTable.Execute operation, because of this we are disabling this capability in this module and it will not proceed." 

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($partitionKey) -or [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rowKey))
{
    Throw $cosmosDBEmptyKeysErrorMessage
}
```

}

function Get-AzureStorageTableTable
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Gets a Table object, it can be from Azure Storage Table or Cosmos DB in preview support.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Gets a Table object, it can be from Azure Storage Table or Cosmos DB in preview support.
    .PARAMETER resourceGroup
        Resource Group where the Azure Storage Account or Cosmos DB are located
    .PARAMETER tableName
        Name of the table to retrieve
    .PARAMETER storageAccountName
        Storage Account name where the table lives
    .EXAMPLE
        # Getting storage table object
        $resourceGroup = "myResourceGroup"
        $storageAccount = "myStorageAccountName"
        $tableName = "table01"
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTabletable -resourceGroup $resourceGroup -tableName $tableName -storageAccountName $storageAccount
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="AzureRmTableStorage",Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$resourceGroup,

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$tableName,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="AzureRmTableStorage",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="AzureTableStorage",Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$storageAccountName
)

$nullTableErrorMessage = [string]::Empty

switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
{
    "AzureRmTableStorage"
        {
            $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName).Context    
            $nullTableErrorMessage = "Table $tableName could not be retrieved from Storage Account $storageAccountName on resource group $resourceGroupName"
        }
    "AzureTableStorage"
        {
            $saContext = (Get-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName).Context
            $nullTableErrorMessage = "Table $tableName could not be retrieved from Classic Storage Account $storageAccountName"
        }
}

[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable]$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Creating a new table if one does not exist
if ($table -eq $null)
{
    [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable]$table = New-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext
}

# Checking if there a table got returned
if ($table -eq $null)
{
    throw $nullTableErrorMessage
}

# Returns the table object
return [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable]$table
```

}

function Add-StorageTableRow
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Adds a row/entity to a specified table
    .DESCRIPTION
        Adds a row/entity to a specified table
    .PARAMETER Table
        Table object of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable where the entity will be added
    .PARAMETER PartitionKey
        Identifies the table partition
    .PARAMETER RowKey
        Identifies a row within a partition
    .PARAMETER Property
        Hashtable with the columns that will be part of the entity. e.g. @{"firstName"="Paulo";"lastName"="Marques"}
    .PARAMETER UpdateExisting
        Signalizes that command should update existing row, if such found by partitionKey and rowKey. If not found, new row is added.
    .EXAMPLE
        # Adding a row
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext
        Add-StorageTableRow -table $table -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey ([guid]::NewGuid().tostring()) -property @{"firstName"="Paulo";"lastName"="Costa";"role"="presenter"}
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $table,

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [String]$partitionKey,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [String]$rowKey,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [hashtable]$property,
[Switch]$UpdateExisting
)

# Creates the table entity with mandatory partitionKey and rowKey arguments
$entity = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity,$assemblySN" -ArgumentList $partitionKey, $rowKey

# Adding the additional columns to the table entity
foreach ($prop in $property.Keys)
{
    if ($prop -ne "TableTimestamp")
    {
        $entity.Properties.Add($prop, $property.Item($prop))
    }
}
    if($UpdateExisting)
{
    return ($table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation,$assemblySN]::insertorreplace(`$entity)")))
}
else
{
    return ($table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation,$assemblySN]::insert(`$entity)")))
}
```

}

function Get-PSObjectFromEntity
{
    # Internal function
    # Converts entities output from the ExecuteQuery method of table into an array of PowerShell Objects

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $entityList
)

$returnObjects = @()

if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($entityList))
{
    foreach ($entity in $entityList)
    {
        $entityNewObj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
        $entity.Properties.Keys | ForEach-Object {Add-Member -InputObject $entityNewObj -Name $_ -Value $entity.Properties[$_].PropertyAsObject -MemberType NoteProperty}

        # Adding table entity other attributes
        Add-Member -InputObject $entityNewObj -Name "PartitionKey" -Value $entity.PartitionKey -MemberType NoteProperty
        Add-Member -InputObject $entityNewObj -Name "RowKey" -Value $entity.RowKey -MemberType NoteProperty
        Add-Member -InputObject $entityNewObj -Name "TableTimestamp" -Value $entity.Timestamp -MemberType NoteProperty
        Add-Member -InputObject $entityNewObj -Name "Etag" -Value $entity.Etag -MemberType NoteProperty

        $returnObjects += $entityNewObj
    }
}

return $returnObjects
```

}

function Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Returns all rows/entities from a storage table - no filtering
    .DESCRIPTION
        Returns all rows/entities from a storage table - no filtering
    .PARAMETER Table
        Table object of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable to retrieve entities
    .EXAMPLE
        # Getting all rows
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext
        Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll -table $table
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $table
    )

```
# No filtering

$tableQuery = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery,$assemblySN"
$result = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($tableQuery)

if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result))
{
    return (Get-PSObjectFromEntity -entityList $result)
}
```

}

function Get-AzureStorageTableRowByPartitionKey
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Returns one or more rows/entities based on Partition Key
    .DESCRIPTION
        Returns one or more rows/entities based on Partition Key
    .PARAMETER Table
        Table object of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable to retrieve entities
    .PARAMETER PartitionKey
        Identifies the table partition
    .EXAMPLE
        # Getting rows by partition Key
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext
        Get-AzureStorageTableRowByPartitionKey -table $table -partitionKey $newPartitionKey
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $table,

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [string]$partitionKey
)

# Filtering by Partition Key


$tableQuery = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery,$assemblySN"

[string]$filter = `
    [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey",`
    [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,$partitionKey)

$tableQuery.FilterString = $filter

$result = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($tableQuery)

if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result))
{
    return (Get-PSObjectFromEntity -entityList $result)
}
```

}

function Get-AzureStorageTableRowByColumnName
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Returns one or more rows/entities based on a specified column and its value
    .DESCRIPTION
        Returns one or more rows/entities based on a specified column and its value
    .PARAMETER Table
        Table object of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable to retrieve entities
    .PARAMETER ColumnName
        Column name to compare the value to
    .PARAMETER Value
        Value that will be looked for in the defined column
    .PARAMETER Operator
        Supported comparison operator. Valid values are "Equal","GreaterThan","GreaterThanOrEqual","LessThan" ,"LessThanOrEqual" ,"NotEqual"
    .EXAMPLE
        # Getting row by firstname
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext
        Get-AzureStorageTableRowByColumnName -table $table -columnName "firstName" -value "Paulo" -operator Equal
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $table,

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$columnName,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="byString",Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [string]$value,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="byGuid",Mandatory=$true)]
    [guid]$guidValue,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [validateSet("Equal","GreaterThan","GreaterThanOrEqual","LessThan" ,"LessThanOrEqual" ,"NotEqual")]
    [string]$operator
)

# Filtering by Partition Key

$tableQuery = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery,$assemblySN"

if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "byString") {
    [string]$filter = `
        [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition($columnName,[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.QueryComparisons]::$operator,$value)
}

if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "byGuid") {
    [string]$filter = `
        [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterConditionForGuid($columnName,[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.QueryComparisons]::$operator,$guidValue)
}

$tableQuery.FilterString = $filter

$result = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($tableQuery)


if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result))
{
    return (Get-PSObjectFromEntity -entityList $result)
}
```

}

function Get-AzureStorageTableRowByCustomFilter
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Returns one or more rows/entities based on custom filter.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Returns one or more rows/entities based on custom filter. This custom filter can be
        built using the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery class or direct text.
    .PARAMETER Table
        Table object of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable to retrieve entities
    .PARAMETER customFilter
        Custom filter string.
    .EXAMPLE
        # Getting row by firstname by using the class Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext
        Get-AzureStorageTableRowByCustomFilter -table $table -customFilter $finalFilter
    .EXAMPLE
        # Getting row by firstname by using text filter directly (oData filter format)
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext
        Get-AzureStorageTableRowByCustomFilter -table $table -customFilter "(firstName eq 'User1') and (lastName eq 'LastName1')"
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $table,

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$customFilter
)

# Filtering by Partition Key
$tableQuery = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery,$assemblySN"

$tableQuery.FilterString = $customFilter

$result = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($tableQuery)

if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result))
{
    return (Get-PSObjectFromEntity -entityList $result)
}
```

}

function Update-AzureStorageTableRow
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Updates a table entity
    .DESCRIPTION
        Updates a table entity. To work with this cmdlet, you need first retrieve an entity with one of the Get-AzureStorageTableRow cmdlets available
        and store in an object, change the necessary properties and then perform the update passing this modified entity back, through Pipeline or as argument.
        Notice that this cmdlet accepts only one entity per execution. 
        This cmdlet cannot update Partition Key and/or RowKey because it uses those two values to locate the entity to update it, if this operation is required
        please delete the old entity and add the new one with the updated values instead.
    .PARAMETER Table
        Table object of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable where the entity exists
    .PARAMETER Entity
        The entity/row with new values to perform the update.
    .EXAMPLE
        # Updating an entity
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext 
        [string]$filter = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition("firstName",[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,"User1")
        $person = Get-AzureStorageTableRowByCustomFilter -table $table -customFilter $filter
        $person.lastName = "New Last Name"
        $person | Update-AzureStorageTableRow -table $table
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $table,

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $entity
)

# Only one entity at a time can be updated
$updatedEntityList = @()
$updatedEntityList += $entity

if ($updatedEntityList.Count -gt 1)
{
    throw "Update operation can happen on only one entity at a time, not in a list/array of entities."
}

$updatedEntity = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity,$assemblySN" -ArgumentList $entity.PartitionKey, $entity.RowKey

# Iterating over PS Object properties to add to the updated entity 
foreach ($prop in $entity.psobject.Properties)
{
    if (($prop.name -ne "PartitionKey") -and ($prop.name -ne "RowKey") -and ($prop.name -ne "Timestamp") -and ($prop.name -ne "Etag") -and ($prop.name -ne "TableTimestamp"))
    {
        $updatedEntity.Properties.Add($prop.name, $prop.Value)
    }
}

$updatedEntity.ETag = $entity.Etag

# Updating the dynamic table entity to the table
return ($table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation,$assemblySN]::Replace(`$updatedEntity)")))
```

}

function Remove-AzureStorageTableRow
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Remove-AzureStorageTableRow - Removes a specified table row
    .DESCRIPTION
        Remove-AzureStorageTableRow - Removes a specified table row. It accepts multiple deletions through the Pipeline when passing entities returned from the Get-AzureStorageTableRow
        available cmdlets. It also can delete a row/entity using Partition and Row Key properties directly.
    .PARAMETER Table
        Table object of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageTable where the entity exists
    .PARAMETER Entity (ParameterSetName=byEntityPSObjectObject)
        The entity/row with new values to perform the deletion.
    .PARAMETER PartitionKey (ParameterSetName=byPartitionandRowKeys)
        Partition key where the entity belongs to.
    .PARAMETER RowKey (ParameterSetName=byPartitionandRowKeys)
        Row key that uniquely identifies the entity within the partition.
    .EXAMPLE
        # Deleting an entry by entity PS Object
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext 
        [string]$filter1 = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition("firstName",[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,"Paulo")
        [string]$filter2 = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition("lastName",[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,"Marques")
        [string]$finalFilter = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery]::CombineFilters($filter1,"and",$filter2)
        $personToDelete = Get-AzureStorageTableRowByCustomFilter -table $table -customFilter $finalFilter
        $personToDelete | Remove-AzureStorageTableRow -table $table
    .EXAMPLE
        # Deleting an entry by using partitionkey and row key directly
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext 
        Remove-AzureStorageTableRow -table $table -partitionKey "TableEntityDemoFullList" -rowKey "399b58af-4f26-48b4-9b40-e28a8b03e867"
    .EXAMPLE
        # Deleting everything
        $saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
        $table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext 
        Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll -table $table | Remove-AzureStorageTableRow -table $table
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $table,

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ParameterSetName="byEntityPSObjectObject")]
    $entity,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="byPartitionandRowKeys")]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [string]$partitionKey,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="byPartitionandRowKeys")]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [string]$rowKey
)

begin
{
    $updatedEntityList = @()
    $updatedEntityList += $entity

    if ($updatedEntityList.Count -gt 1)
    {
        throw "Delete operation cannot happen on an array of entities, altough you can pipe multiple items."
    }

    $results = @()
}

process
{
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "byEntityPSObjectObject")
    {
        $partitionKey = $entity.PartitionKey
        $rowKey = $entity.RowKey
    }

    $entityToDelete = invoke-expression "[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity,$assemblySN](`$table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation,$assemblySN]::Retrieve(`$partitionKey,`$rowKey))).Result"

    if ($entityToDelete -ne $null)
    {
        $results += $table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation,$assemblySN]::Delete(`$entityToDelete)"))
    }
}

end
{
    return ,$results
}
```

}

## Aliases

New-Alias -Name Add-AzureStorageTableRow -Value Add-StorageTableRow

Comment: Could you tell me what you want to do？

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to use PowerShell to manage Azure table Storage. If so you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460310/azure-table-storage-a-script-to-populate-new-column-for-existing-tables/57463116#57463116. Besides, could you please describe your issue in detaill and tell me what you do?

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, you want to use PowerShell to manage Azure table Storage. If so, you can use the module [AzTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzTable/2.0.1) to implement it.

For example

```
Install-Module -Name AzTable

$groupName=""
$StorageAccountName = ""
$StorageAccountKey = ""
$vaule=" "
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$tables = Get-AzStorageTable -Context $context
Foreach($table in $tables){
    $table = Get-AzTableTable -storageAccountName $StorageAccountName -resourceGroup $groupName="" -TableName
    $entities=Get-AzTableRow -Table $table
    ForEach($e in $entities){
        $entity = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity($e.PartitionKey,$e.RowKey)
        $entity.Properties.Add("Name", $vaue)
        $table.Execute([Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrMerge($entity))
        Get-AzTableRow -Table $table -PartitionKey $e.PartitionKey -RowKey $e.RowKey
    }

}
```

For more details, please refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell